# How to make slides to autoplay in Splidejs

Tags: splidejs

I am newbie to Splidejs.

I want to  make slides in my web page to be autoplayed when page loaded.

I tried with this code but it doesn't accomplish my task
(I set autoplay property to true).

```
     document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function () {
     new Splide('#image-slider').mount() , {
    
     autoplay:true, 
     type   : 'loop',
     cover  : true,
     height : '1000rem',
     perPage:3,
     };
     } );
```

Comment: Your not giving the community any details. Please review the following page, then try re-asking your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @JayDev Do you mean details like html part of my code?

Comment: Your webpage has to consist of more code than this. And what happens when you try to execute the code above? How do you know the code is not working? Have you tried to solve the issue at all? Most importantly, are you getting any errors in the console, or browser? (should be getting errors in both)

Answer (score 1):

I just changed the code to the following code and the problem solved.

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    new Splide( '#image-slider', {
      arrows :'false' ,
      type    : 'loop',
      perPage : 1,
      autoplay: true,
      cover: false,
      height : '100rem',
    }).mount();
});
  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new Splide( '.splide',  {
    reducedMotion: {
        interval: 4000,
        speed: 800,
        autoplay: "play"
      }        
} ).mount();
```